# ApolloClient GraphQL error: line 1:23 no viable alternative at character '_'

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to run a query using `ApolloClient` in node.js, and I receive the following error:

```
Error: GraphQL error: line 1:23 no viable alternative at character '_'
      at new ApolloError (node_modules/src/errors/ApolloError.ts:56:5)
      at node_modules/src/core/QueryManager.ts:515:31
      at node_modules/src/core/QueryManager.ts:1036:11
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at node_modules/src/core/QueryManager.ts:1035:10
          at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (node_modules/src/core/QueryManager.ts:1029:18)
      at Object.next (node_modules/src/core/QueryManager.ts:1130:18)
      at notifySubscription (node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:130:18)
      at onNotify (node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:165:3)
      at SubscriptionObserver.next (node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:219:7)
      at node_modules/apollo-link-dedup/src/dedupLink.ts:60:47
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object.next (node_modules/apollo-link-dedup/src/dedupLink.ts:60:31)
      at notifySubscription (node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:130:18)
      at onNotify (node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:165:3)
      at SubscriptionObserver.next (node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:219:7)
      at Object.next (node_modules/apollo-link-error/src/index.ts:60:22)
      at notifySubscription (node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:130:18)
      at onNotify (node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:165:3)
      at SubscriptionObserver.next (node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:219:7)
      at node_modules/apollo-link-http/src/httpLink.ts:142:20
```

This is the code snippet:

```
require('cross-fetch/polyfill');
const ApolloBoost = require('apollo-boost');
const ApolloClient = ApolloBoost.default;
const gql = require('graphql-tag');
const {
    url,
} = require('./utils');

const events = await client.query({
    query: gql`
        query EventsByTimeFrame(
            $customerId: String!
            $filters: [Field]!
        ) {
            events(customerId: $customerId, filters: $filters) {
                entityId
                values
            }
        }
    `,
    variables: {
        customerId,
        filters: {
            key: 'key',
            value: 'waste',
        },
    },
});
```

When I try to run the same query via GraphiQL, it works well. Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: Not sure where that error is coming from, but I can at least see your variables object is not correct. According to your query, `filters` should be an array of `fields` but you are passing in an object.

Comment: I tried with an Array of such objects as well and it didn't work. Additionally, both conventions work in GraphiQL.